# use of "for which"

Tags: subordinate-clauses

is the use of "for which" correct in the following sentence? Thanks

One day the sales team informed us that they are going to send 10 input files **for which** we will use to run some sensitivity analysis.

Comment: The words that follow _for which_ , "we will use to run", makes your question difficult to answer. Are you going to use the files to run a sensitivity analysis (or some sensitivity analyses), or do you mean "10 input files for which we will run some sensitivity analyses"? (Note that analysis should be plural if you're going to use the adjective "some".)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is incorrect, but it depends on precisely what you mean.

I think that you intend to say:

> One day the sales team informed us that they are going to send 10
> input files *for us to use* to run some sensitivity analysis.

EDIT

The following is what I would probably write myself but this is for reasons of style rather than grammar or correctness.

> One day the sales team informed us that they are going to send 10
> input files for us to use as a basis for some sensitivity analysis.

Comment: Alternately, you could say "One day the sales team informed us that they are going to send 10 input files **which** we will use to run some sensitivity analysis."